Why doesn't Josephus mention the golden calf?
When studying the text of the Jewish Antiquities written by the Roman historian Josephus, I found that events related to Moses and the travels of Hebrews in the wilderness are covered in considerable detail. At the same time, Josephus does not mention at all the event of the Golden Calf. What is the reason for the omission?

From wikipedia: "In another example, apparently due to his concern with pagan antisemitism, Josephus omitted the entire episode of the golden calf from his account of the Israelites at Mount Sinai. It has been suggested that he was afraid that the biblical account might be employed by Alexandrian antisemites to lend credence to their allegation that the Jews worshiped an ass's head in the Temple (cf. Apion 2:80, 114, 120; Tacitus, Histories 5:4)." I do not find this remotely convincing. after all, he tells us about the ass slur. Why would a golden calf be embarrassing - which would be normal.

After the Golden Calf, God offers Moses to kill all the Jews and start a new nation out of him. Perhaps Josephus wanted to downplay how God's abandonment of the Jewish people is on the table.

Gregory E. Sterling, "When Silence Is Golden: The Omission of the Golden Calf Story in Josephus", in: Golden Calf Traditions in Early Judaism, Christianity, and Islam, pp. 87-96 discussed the possibility you suggested in the comments regarding the libel of the statue in the Temple, but rejected it on the grounds of Josephus still mentioning Jeroboam's two golden calves later in Antiquities, as well as multiple other instances of Israelite idolatry.
He suggested a combination of two other reasons instead:

Tremendous respect for Aaron. Other ancient Hellenistic Jewish authors had difficulties with Aaron's embarrassing sin, and more so Josephus, who wrote about Aaron in glowing terms elsewhere. In this omission, Josephus was not different from Philo and the later Pseudo-Philo, who also skirted over the topic. Philo did mention the calf, but did not state that Aaron created it. Pseudo-Philo restructured the narrative so it'd be more clear that Aaron did it because he knew that he would be in mortal danger if he did not comply with the nation's demands.

Respect for the sacredness of the tablets and the commandments - Josephus did not want it be known that Moshe had broken the first set of tablets in anger, which were sacred in his (Josephus's) eyes. This second reason explains why Josephus didn't pursue a description similar to that of Philo or Pseudo-Philo (i.e., freeing Aaron from blame), instead preferring to omit the story entirely.



My understanding is that Antiquities was written for a Roman audience and Josephus was trying to portray the Jews in as favorable and sophisticated a light as possible.

Actually a more detailed answer is given on wikipedia. Maybe you could offer this link or quote? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiquities_of_the_Jews
